# How ImageMagick readimage from a relative path WampServer64

Tags: imagick

I'm testing the php_imagick version 3.4.4.7.4 against a WampServer64 installation using

```
<?php
/* Create the Imagick object */
$im = new Imagick();
 
/* Read the image file */
try {
    $im->readImage( "test.jpg" );
} catch( \ImagickException $e ) {
    die( $e );
}
/* Thumbnail the image ( width 100, preserve dimensions ) */
$im->thumbnailImage( 100, null );
 
/* Write the thumbail to disk */
$im->writeImage( 'th_test.png' );
 
/* Free resources associated to the Imagick object */
$im->destroy();
```

It results in raised ImagickException No such file or directory. The file sits in the same folder as the php file.
When I replace 'test.jpg' by an absolute path the code works but the resulting file at writeImage ends up in the folder C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41

Is this normal behaviour? I don't see a remark in https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.readimage.php that paths should be absolute. Is this a quirk in WampServer64?

Comment: It could be a WampServer64 problem. I have done it in the past with a XAMPP installation although I do not have imagick installed to try now. I have tested the code on my webserver and it works.

Comment: Thanks for testing, bonzo. I do get similar results with xampp. the create th_test.php ends up in my C:\xampp folder